# phrasal verb "look down"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I want to express that I am upstairs in a building and observing events down the street. Which sentence does it describe in accordance with standard English:

*1. I am looking down from the window.*

*2. I am looking down the window.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the window is more of a place then an object, so number 1 would be correct 2 would be incorrect. In number 1 are you expressing that you are watching from the window.

> I am looking down from the window.
>
> I am looking down the window.

That sentence in the first part (*I am looking *) doesn't change through both 1 and 2. But the second part (*down from the window / down the window*) would change. 1 Means that you are looking down to the street **from** the window. (Which is exactly what I think you mean), 2 More likely means that you are looking down **at** the window not **from** it. (Which I'm pretty sure you are not trying to express that).

So answer would be 1.

Comment: Specifically, "I am looking down the <object>" means "I am looking down along the <object>, looking for things in, on, or near the <object>, or at the end of the <object>".  Compare to "I am looking down the shaft" or "I am looking down the street".

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely option one - "from the window":

"I'm looking down from the third floor window where I can see the whole market"